# Where does /etc map to on the host system under MSYS?

Tags: msys

I want to be sure that my changes to `/etc` will be persisted between restarts of MinGW. However, trying to write to `/etc` results in *permission denied* errors, so I am starting to think it is just mapped in memory and does not actually exist on the host file system at all but since I can't find any documentation about this I'd appreciate confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

/etc is a real location that depends on a relative install directory.  On my system, the location is:

```
 C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc
```

Naturally, your install location may vary.

As you may recall, Windows has a propensity for locking directories when something running sees the folder as its working directory.  It is very likely that *permission denied* errors are due to run-time state.  If you wish to save/restore /etc, this probably must occur before any MSYS processes are running, or all MSYS processes that were already running need to be stopped.

A workaround for perpetually locked directories, when one cannot find/remove the "lock", is to rename the directory, copy in a new one, and delete the renamed copy after a reboot.